# Resize multidimensional array in R

Tags: r, arrays

Im trying to expand the size of multidimensional array.

More particullary I have an 10x3x3 (rowsxcolumnsxmatrix) array and I want to expand it to become an 20x3x3 array.
I want to keep my current data in the first 10 rows and just resize their rows so I can add more data. Ideally the new rows should have 0s.

I can do this with loops but Im wondering if there is a function that can do the whole process automatically.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a faster and more accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library `abind`.

```
library(abind)
v1=numeric(10)
v2=numeric(3)
a=array(c(v1, v2), dim = c(10, 3, 3))
res <- abind(originalArray, a, along = 1)
```